# VBA Regex to match Two sets of Four Digits with String

Tags: regex, vba

Im trying to make a Excel Regex pattern to find a certain string. This what Im trying:

**I'm trying to make it match 0 and 0000 to 9999**

```
StringToMatch = "a75z6878"

Dim objRegExp As New RegExp  
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")  
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True  
objRegExp.Global = True  

objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])[a-z]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]([0-9]{1-4})[a-z]([0-9]{1-4})"

If objRegExp.Test(StringToMatch) Then MsgBox(Found!)
```

I have tried different patterns but none work.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong in `objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z]([0-9]{1-4})[a-z]([0-9]{1-4})"`

The quantifier must be specified as `{m,n}` and not `{m-n}`

change the regex to

```
[a-z][0-9]{1,4}[a-z][0-9]{1,4}
```

For example see the link http://regex101.com/r/wA2qM3/1

OR a shorter version like

```
 [a-z]\d{1,4}[a-z]\d{1,4}
```

Comment: You are right about his problem, but you've got some typos in your fix: parens don't match. But while you're at it, just remove the parens; they're not needed. And `\d` would shorten it even further.